# jtable getting more than 100 rows

Tags: jtable

Hi i have a java application which takes data from a oracle database. But the problem is it will only display the first 100 rows. how do i display the rest of the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to make a JTable with 1000 rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248757/need-to-make-a-jtable-with-1000-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add any number of rows to your JTable without any custom modifications. It is likely that your query returns only 100 rows while you expect more.

It may happen when a `LIMIT` is automatically added by the search engine when you query the database.

You should check the query that is being executed (not sent, but executed). Try Adding `LIMIT 200` to your query and see what happens.